# Why can't I answer a question on "Home Improvement" although I have a very high reputation on other networks?

Tags: discussion

I don't get it. I can't answer a question on Home Improvement although I have a high reputation (2400 points) on stackoverflow, and also good scores on other networks.

What's the wisdom of this rule?

Comment: It takes a minute sometimes to get the bonus 100 rep for being trusted on other SE sites. You have it now, so you could just delete this question.

Comment: Can you link the question you were trying to answer?

Comment: @Tyson I already had the 100 points bonus, but it was mentioned that the 100 points for being trusted on other networks will not be considered for this rule.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Where could all these flies be coming from?  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/13667/where-could-all-these-flies-be-coming-from

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presuming you came to diy.se becuase you saw a `Hot Network Question`, it's very likely that question benefited a little too much from the visibility, and so was "protected".  This is disclosed near the bottom of the question like this:

> **protected** by ABCDEF yesterday
>
> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation *on this site* **(the association bonus does not count)**. (Emphasis mine).
>
> Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?